# Big O of various versions of binary search

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was given the following code and was told to find the best and worst case running times in big theta notation.

```
def find(a, target):
    x = 0
    y = len(a)
    while x < y:
        m = (x+y)/2
        if a[m] < target:
            x = m+1
        elif a[m] > target: 
            y = m
        else:
            return m
    return -1
```

I know that the running time of this code in the worst case is O(lg(n)). But the question I was given if the fifth line was changed from "m=(x+y)/2" to "m=(2*x+y)/3" would the running time change?

My intuition is that the running time gets a little larger as it is no longer cutting the list in half like binary search should do which is less efficient, but I am not sure how to calculate what big O would be at this point

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer theory, not a practical coding problem.

Comment: Hint: use the master theorem.

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/. I've flagged it for migration.

Comment: @Martjin I realize that it is more theory but I didn't feel it belonged on mathexchange as it uses code, which might be not as well received over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that for worst case, we are searching for the element that resides last in the array of N elements.

After 1st iteration, the list shall reduce to 2N/3.

After 2nd iteration, the list shall reduce to 4N/9

.
.
.

After (k-1)th iteration the list shall reduce to 2 elements

After kth iteration we shall finally find our candidate.

Hence N * (power(2/3,k)) = 1.

k ~ log (N) to base 1.5